# D3 Treemap with fisheye

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js, treemap, fisheye

I have a large dataset being visualized by a treemap. There are 2 problems I am facing:

1. Load and display times on localhost are very slow. Expect worse performance over ajax calls. My dataset is 400 parents, each with approximately 10-15 children. A parent only have children (children do not have children)
2. Because there are 400 parents on the top level the initial treemap is very crowded. What I would like to implement is the [fisheye](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) functionality. However, my code below does not work, meaning when I move the mouse over the treemap I do not see the fisheye. I see the mouse x-y being correctly outputted to the console. but not the image.

```
var svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
      .attr("class", "chart")
      .style("width", w + "px")
      .style("height", h + "px")
      .append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)
      .append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");'

  d3.json("../data/flare.json", function(data) {

  node = root = data;

  var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

  var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "cell")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

  cell.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parent.name); });

  cell.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

  d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
    treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
    zoom(node);
  });

  var xFisheye = d3.fisheye.scale(d3.scale.identity).domain([0, w]).focus(360),
  yFisheye = d3.fisheye.scale(d3.scale.identity).domain([0, h]).focus(90);

  svg.on("mousemove", function() {
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        xFisheye.focus(mouse[0]);
        yFisheye.focus(mouse[1]);
        redraw();
      });

      function redraw() {
          cell.attr("x1", xFisheye).attr("x2", xFisheye);
          cell.attr("y1", xFisheye).attr("y2", xFisheye);
      }       
});
```

Comment: Could you define 'does not work' and provide an example (eg. fiddle)?

Comment: sorry. i mean the treemap does not expand into a fisheye when moused over, even though the mouse x-y coordinate are there

Comment: For starters, you are borrowing code that is applying the fisheye distortion along `line` elements drawn in cartesian space to a `g` element (cell) **without any modifications**. As you can see, it does not work. But, taking a step back, consider that in normal conditions, the treemap already scales over large datasets by using a drill-down zoom effect and there would not seem to be much of a gain by adding a distortion to it. To handle the very large number of parents in your case, I suggest you consider adding some higher category(ies) to the data to reduce the number of first-level parents.